how to make airflow webui can display chinese character?
I've successfully deployed an Airflow service on my Ubuntu server. However, I encountered errors when attempting to set arguments using Chinese characters. For instance, when I set a DAG's owner to a Chinese character, serialization fails and the characters are converted to '???'. How can I resolve this issue?
Despite checking the 'airflow.cfg' configuration file, I couldn't find any relevant settings for encoding.
